# p:calendar Time slider Losing Hours and Minutes

Tags: java, datetime, jsf, primefaces

The issue I'm facing is when I try to change the time hours slider in **primefaces 6.1** calendar, I loose most of the hours. Most of the time only one hour change is detected.

I have looked into the following.
[Losing hours/minutes when Ajax enabled](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=12871)

Code for Calendar. (This code was already written. I just have to fix the sliding issue)

```
<p:calendar widgetVar="collectedDate" tabindex="50"
                            value="#{caseController.selectedCase.caseCollectedDate}"
                            converter="DateConverter"
                            converterMessage="Please enter valid date time format" pattern="MM/dd/yy HH:mm"
                            maxdate="#{viewUtilityBean.currentDate}">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="@this,:growl"
            listener="#{caseController.onDateCollectedSelect()}"/>
</p:calendar>
```

DateConverter

```
Date date1 = null;
    try {
        if (!value.contains(":")) {
            date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse(value);
            value = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm").format(date1.getTime());
            date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm").parse(value);
        } else {
            date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm").parse(value);
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If the current time in the calendar is 15:00 and I drag the slider to 12:00. The updated time it shows is 14:00 while it should show 12:00.

Is there any way, I can call this ajax after the whole date and time is selected. Not after every little change in the slider.

This is timezone we are using in our app.

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Did you try removing @this in the update?

Comment: @Melloware yes already tried that

Comment: How is your timezone configured?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I have updated the question regarding timezone. Second, it is not because of timezone. It because of the ajax as soon as there is a one hour change in time, the ajax is called due to which we lose the time.

Comment: What is going on in `DateConverter`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JasperdeVries sorry for that. I should have provided it first. I have updated the question. You can see there is not much functionality in DateConverter

Comment: State your PF version please!

Comment: @Kukeltje question updated.

Comment: does 6.1 already have the dataPicker? (replacement of calendar) if so, you can try that.

Comment: @Kukeltje No Sir. It doesn't have. Unfortunately, that's why I have to stick to Calendar.